# Update a row with data from another row within the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

```
UPDATE user SET 
                tw_oauth_token=(SELECT tw_oauth_token FROM user WHERE id=27),
                tw_oauth_token_secret = (SELECT tw_oauth_token_secret FROM user WHERE id=27),
                tw_user_id = (SELECT tw_user_id FROM user WHERE id=27),
                handler = (SELECT handler FROM user WHERE id=27),
                merged=1 WHERE id=26
```

The idea is to select data from user table where id = 27 and update the same table where id = 26.

I am having the following error:

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'user' for update in FROM clause
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: First result on google, first related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE  user a
        CROSS JOIN user b
SET     a.tw_oauth_token = b.tw_oauth_token,
        a.tw_oauth_token_secret = b.tw_oauth_token_secret,
        a.tw_user_id = b.tw_user_id,
        a.handler = b.handler,
        a.mrged = 1
WHERE   a.ID = 26 AND
        b.ID = 27
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is a CROSS JOIN rather than a NATURAL or INNER JOIN; it seems like the salient part is that it's a self-JOIN user AS a joined to user AS b --- but where the "AS" syntactic sugar is being left out.  (Personally I prefer to see the "AS" keyword, especially in discussion and documentation).

Comment: @JimDennis you cannot use `INNER JOIN` here since you cannot determine where the record will be joined. here's what happens with the statement above: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11f5f/2

Comment: @JimDennis the result if you use `NATURAL JOIN` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/beb51/2 which doens't give you correct data.

Comment: @JimDennis lastly, I'm not fun of using `AS` myself as it is optional.

Comment: Thanks for the sqlfiddle links.  I really need to start using that.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to create a virtual table based on your table then update the `user` table with `SELECT` statements on that View. Something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW view_user AS
SELECT *
FROM user;
```

And then use the view_user in the update.